# Mongo filters: Is there equivalents for these sql statements?

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I need to have something like a subquery in mongo filter. Something like say

```
Select * from table where column_1 < column_2

Select * from table where column_1 < (select max(column_1) from table)
```

Are there mongodb equivalents for the above sql statements?

**UPDATE**

After reading docs I figured out that I can do `Select * from table where column_1 < column_2` by using mongo `$where`

But I still do not know the answer for doing `Select * from table where column_1 < (select max(column_1) from table)`

Answer (score 2):

```
Select * from table where column_1 < (select max(column_1) from table)
```

Is quite a simple one actually. There is no projection of the table in MongoDB but fortunately this query is quite simple:

```
var max_doc=db.collection.find().sort({column_1:-1}).limit(1) ;
    // Will get to the row with the max value for column_1

if(mac_doc!==null)
    var result=db.collection.find({column_1:{$lt:max_doc['column_1']}})
```

That would be 100x more performant and better than a `$where` for starters.

The first query can actually be performed with the aggregation framework most likely using the $cmp operator: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/cmp/

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {$project: {_id:'$_id',s:{$cmp:['$column_1','$column_2']}}},
    {$match: {s:{$lt:0}}}
])
```

Which would also most likely be better than a `$where`, even with the new 2.4 changes (which only help with MRs really).

Answer (score 1):

you can use `$where` operator. refer this for usage of [$where](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/where/#op._S_where)

Comment: Thanks Peeyush. That is only parts of the question. Is it possible to do the second thing?

Comment: Come on, a line answer, plus a `$where`? Wouldn't something like this be better through other methods? There are a few